AG Grid - SSRM - use row index data provided by the service
Is there a way to override the startRow/endRow values AG Grid uses when SSRM?  For example, if my block size is 10, after the first retrieval of data, AG Grid would specify 11 as the startRow in the next request.  I would like to be able to tell AG Grid what the next row is going to be based on the previous response from the service instead of AG Grid computing the value.  Is this possibe?
I looked through the documentation but this does not seem possible
